# Android and jets3t? Library Issues

Tags: android, amazon-s3, storage, google-cloud-storage, jets3t

I am trying to use jets3t0.9.0 in my android application but running into classnotfoundexceptions and noclassdeffounderror. I added the httpcore4.2 and httpclient 4.2, logging and the commons-io jar files to the build library.

Thanks
Droidment

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I'm having similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Jets3t-0.9.0 has an major update to use httpclient library 4.x instead of 3.x. There are 4 libraries which it needs during compile -

Apache Commons Logging 1.1.1
Apache Commons Codec 1.4
HttpClient 4.1.1
Java XMLBuilder 0.4

Jars for these comes along with jets3t suite, you just have to include them in your application.

Also paste name of some of the classes which are not getting found?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, best answer is do *NOT* use JetS3t for Android.  Use the Amazon AWS library instead.

More info here on why after I dug into it a bit:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jets3t-users/vCq4pwXSPN8